# How can I merge scope change watch

Tags: angularjs

All:

I am pretty new to Angular directive, I wonder how can I merge $watch together, for example:

If I render a chart directive, either data change or width change or height change will lead to render, but when the init stage, all of those three may change together, which lead chart to render three times, but only one render needed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the lodash library, especially `debounce` method. With it you can do something like that:

```
$scope.render =_.debounce($scope.oldRenderingMethod);
```

And then in each event handler:

```
_.defer($scope.render);
```

`debounce` takes care that the function is not executed more often than every x seconds (look at the docs), while `defer` ensures that the rendering of the canvas does not have a negative impact on the ui responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

You can check for new and old values in your watch function and see if the old value was not set.

```js
$scope.$watch('myvariable', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (oldVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
    //the old value was defined (initialized)
    //and the new one is different (changed)
  }
}
```

You can also accoomplish the same thing as lodash's defer() by wrapping your action in a settimeout. Both of these essentially push the action into the queue to be run on the next digest cycle.

```js
$scope.$watch('myvariable', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      //do stuff 
    }, 0); //you don't need to actually set the timer, it will still push to the next cycle
  }
}
```

Without code examples this is just the best guess at what you need to do.